# Data integration vs service integration, when each one fits in a business workflow

Tags: integration, esb, mule, pentaho, business-process-management

An interesting question is how pentaho data integration fits and perhaps would be useful in an  environment that involves BPM (bonita software) and ESB Enterprise Service Bus (Mule).

I didn't find any documentation about it. Maybe I`m misunderstood these two conceptions but I really would like to know how and when I can use these two approaches.

To be more clear, how I can use pentaho data integration to improve the business workflow and be a tool to work together with an ESB platform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a very generic question about how to do system integrations.
You will have your high level (business perspective) business processes guiding your company, probably gathering data from and showing business data through Pentaho and the ESB will be in charge of handling how the systems used by the business processes communicates with each other. 
I wrote some time ago these slides for jBPM5 but I think it will  help you to understand how all these technologies fits:
http://www.slideshare.net/salaboy/jbpm5-community-training-module-25-bpm-for-developers

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is an integration of Mule and PDI, but it doesnt appear to have been used much.  see here: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7416

There is also an enormous overlap in the tools. Obviously Mule contains ETL functionality - and similarly PDI can do ESB like operations.  So there is good sense in integrating and using the best of both!

Certainly mule/ESB seems to be where it's at with the whole "data in motion" concept.